# Correct PHPDoc for a function that accept zero or many arguments

Tags: php, function, phpdoc

Consider the following function as an example. What is the correct PHPDoc block for that? PhpStorm does not consider it correct.

```
    /**
     * @param mixed $items,...
     * @return array
     */
    function foo()
    {
        return func_get_args();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the inclusion of Variadics(http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) from PHP 5.6 I believe that format is no longer supported, try this one..

```
   /**
     * @param mixed ...$items
     * @return array
     */
    function foo()
    {
        return func_get_args();
    }
```